# How to make certain javascript files render from php using htaccess

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

So I haven't quite figured out the proper structure to use within my .htaccess file for what I am looking to achieve.

What I would like to have happen is any javascript files that are called from a folder (and only that folder) are generated by a php file. I'm not looking to have a .php extension or create multiple files for this.

An example is

```
https://www.domain.com/loads/923as0d9f89089asd.js
```

Would then be sent to something like:

```
https://www.domain.com/loads/js.php
```

Not looking to use a $_GET method on the php either. Basically the php file detects the file name and then does what it is supposed to do from there.

What would be the best way to set this up within an .htaccess file?

Thanks!

Comment: redirect them to a different php file and serve them from there

Comment: Have you already looked at the htaccess concepts of Rewrite and Redirects?

Comment: This might help you: http://htaccesscheatsheet.com/#rewrite-and-redirection. I has a lot of examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside `loads/.htaccess` you can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /loads/

RewriteRule ^[\w-]+\.js$ js.php [L,NC]
```

Inside your `js.php` you need to use `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` to get original JS filename and serve the content.

Comment: That's pretty close. When I use /loads/jaklsdjfkljklasdf.js I get a not found, but if I do /jaklsdjfkljklasdf.js it does in fact allow me to get the url in the /loads/js.php file. Was hoping to have it come from the /loads/ directory and not just be served from top level (ie: /loads/jojklajklsdjfkl.js and not /jaklsdjfkljaklsdf.js)

Comment: If you place above rule in `loads/.htaccess` as I suggested in answer then it will indeed work for `/loads/jaklsdjfkljklasdf.js`.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

You could have something like this (untested, may need modification) :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/loads/(.*).js$
RewriteRule ^/loads/(.*).js$ http://www.domain.com/loads/js.php?file=$1 [P]
```

And your js.php script will be called internally, it will receive the JS filename from GET but it's not visible by the user.
This will use mod_proxy with the [P] flag.
More informations here : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p

Comment: Not looking to have it redirect to the php file at all. Just want the js reference to be handed off to the php file and the php file render the js.

Comment: My exemple code will do an invisible redirect, your user's browser will see for example this url : www.domain.com/loads/myfile.js

Comment: No, your example actually redirects them to the php file and ends up on js.php?file=xxxx

Comment: Try to have mod_proxy activated (a2enmod mod_proxy) and use the [P] flag instead of [L], more info here : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p